# Getting value in the middle of a string

Tags: vb.net

I am try to get value in the middle of a string

My string is

> "arely browning,68097,19

I know I can use a substring and pick a specific place but I want it to work for any line that is format like this

Comment: I am try to get the name browning

Comment: `this is my first time using this website for help`  You should have read [ask] and taken the [tour] first.

Comment: You need to explain what the rules are that say "browning" is the string you want. Is it whatever is between the first space and the next comma? What if the string is "arely lee browning,68097,19", or "arely browning #1,68097,19"or "arely browning ,68097,19"?

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the string remains the same, then this will do it:

```
Dim MyString As String = "arely browning,68097,19"
Dim StringPart As String = Mid(MyString, InStr(MyString, " "), InStr(MyString, ",") - InStr(MyString, " "))
```